# Les mots « billion » en français et « billion » en anglais sont-ils des faux-amis par excellence ?

Tags: faux-amis

Le *Larousse* définie le mot comme suit :

> Un million de millions.

Le *Robert* donne cette définition :

> **moderne** Un million de millions, soit 10<sup>12</sup> (➙ téra-).

En anglais, par contre, le mot « billion » veut incontestablement dire **mille** millions.

S'agit-il alors de faux-amis ?

Comment: Le même pour [*trillion*](https://www.linguee.fr/anglais-francais/traduction/trillion.html)

Comment: « par excellence », là je dirais non.

Comment: @AlexisWilke "billion" est le mot qui signifier des choses différentes dans les deux langues, et qui peut facilement mener à une confusion. Les examples les plus proches, dont je peux penser, sont "mail" et "assister".

Comment: @RogerVadim *Billion* n'a pas besoin de l'anglais pour prêter à confusion, son sens précis étant déjà inconnu de l'écrasante majorité des Français.

Comment: Voir https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89chelles_longue_et_courte pour plus d'information sur l'histoire.

Answer (score 4):

*Billion* est souvent catalogué comme faux-ami mais il faut tempérer cette appellation par le fait qu'on n'emploie plus vraiment *billion* en France depuis longtemps. *Billion* serait plutôt de l'ordre de l'anglicisme aujourd'hui.

Dans la vie courante, on utilise *mille*, *million*, *milliard* puis au-delà, *mille milliards*, *un million de milliards*, *mille millions de milliards*, etc.

Même l'Académie française admet que *[billion](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9B1128)* n'a pas percé :

> **Billion**
> Rare. Mille millions. Syn. vieilli de Milliard. Selon un décret de 1961, le mot Billion a reçu une nouvelle valeur, à savoir un million de millions (10<sup>12</sup>), qui n’est pas entrée dans l’usage.

Voir aussi: [*Current and past meaning of "billion" in BrE*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/358488/)

Answer (score 2):

### Oui

Ces définitions sont exactes: en français un "billion" est bien un million de millions, et non pas un millier de millions (qu'on appellerait un "milliard"). Ces mots sont toujours usités, en tous cas en France métropolitaine, et ceci entraîne évidemment certains quiproquos comme vous l'avez deviné. On peut donc bien affirmer qu'il s'agit de faux amis.

Par contre vous vous trompez en affirmant:

> En anglais, par contre, le mot « billion » veut incontestablement dire mille millions.

C'est bien le cas en anglais américain, mais c'est faux en anglais brittanique où on peut trouver parfois "billions" dans le même sens qu'en français (il s'agit par contre là bel et bien d'un emploi archaique).

Comment: Je n'ai jamais entendu qui que ce soit utiliser billion en français.

Comment: @jlliagre de mon côté ça m'arrive relativement souvent. Pas tous les jours, peut-être même pas tous les mois, mais plus souvent que des mots comme "charpenterie" par exemple, qui sont pourtant loin d'être tombés en désuétude.

Comment: C'est ton droit mais j'imagine que quand tu le fais, tu expliques à tes interlocuteurs la valeur associée à ce mot. On peut difficilement considérer comme un faux-ami un mot dont la signification en français est le plus souvent inconnue ou au mieux incertaine.

Comment: Non, tout le monde autour de moi sens considérer que c'est évident. Quand j'entends ou lit ce mot on ne prend jamais la peine de m'en expliciter le sens.

Comment: On doit vivre dans des mondes parallèles...

Comment: Dans quel milieu naviguez-vous pour entendre cet usage ? Pour ma part, j'ai dû l'ouïr — rarement, dans les milieux aisés ayant fait leurs études à Paris — il y a un demi siècle par des personnes décédées avant ce millénaire (« Cela doit être une dépense qui se compte en billions ! » pour « C'est une somme astronomique ! » :-)

Comment: @Personne un milieu assez diversifié, même si il regroupe surtout des Français (et donc pas de francophones du Québec ou de la Côte d'Ivoire par exemple). Je l'entends principalement dans des contextes scientifiques où on a besoin de compter de très grandes quantités (par exemple des nombres d'opérations effectuées par un ordinateur)

Comment: Les informaticiens parlent de téraoctets (12 zéros entre le 1 et la virgule), ils en sont maintenant au zettaoctet (21 zéros) superficie qui contiendrait toutes les données du monde, mais il est vrai que ceux-là ne sont ni chercheurs, ni de pures scientifiques.

Comment: Je navigue dans ce milieu pas mal de décennies et pour ce type de mesure, j'entends principalement parler de méga, giga, tera, voire péta-opérations (par seconde) et depuis peu exa-opérations (à virgule flottante par seconde) ([1er ordinateur exaflopique](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frontier_(superordinateur))). Les purs scientifiques utilisent les préfixes iso, les puissances de 10.

Comment: ...milieu **depuis** pas mal...